# Mex compiled function not recognized by MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, compilation, linker, mex

I am on a Mac, running OSX 10.9.5. I am running MATLAB 2014a.

I have a function in c++ called `features.cc`. This function is successfully compiled by MATLAB via MEX. However when in MATLAB, I type `features(foo, blah)` or try to use it, it says `Undefined function or variable 'features'`. MATLAB does not recognize it. Why is that? I have checked and I am sure all the paths are included.

For what it's worth, when I perform a MEX, I get a new file in my directory called `features.mexmaci64`

Not sure what to do here. Why does MATLAB not recognize it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it in a network drive?  Regardless, try `rehash path`.

Comment: @chappjc Thanks, I its weird, I had to explicitly go to the directory of the mex file and only then did the function become available. Adding its directory via addpath(genpath('the/path')) did not work for some reason.

Comment: Does `cd(genpath('the/path'))` work or give an error?

Comment: @chappjc It gives an error. FWIW my problem 'works' now, its just that I have to change directories mid way through compilation of different things, so its clunky. :-/